# Как в ASP.NET Core MVC убрать страницу /home/?

Tags: c#, asp-net-core-mvc, .net-7

Сабж. Вот у меня сайт на ASP.NET Core MVC. Есть `HomeController` . Как мне убрать страницу `site.com/home/` Потому что `site.com/home/` и `site.com/` это 2 одинаковые страницы.

Comment: Как и на любом другом сайте... Например на SO также есть `/home`, на сайтах написанных на PHP (например VK), там `/index.php`, бывает еще `/index`, `/index.html`, и так далее, это нормальное поведение, которое есть почти у 90% существующих сайтов, смысл переживать из-за этого... странно)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61891542/5045688 - не?